# How can I do script and custom API versioning of azure mobile services node backend?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We are using azure mobile services node backend for our android and iOS clients. Initially we started with one android and one iOS app and we released one version of android app to play store.

As time passes we have implemented some new features and added few breaking changes which may cause crash to existing users.

Now we want to support both the client versions with the single existing azure mobile service.We don't want to give force update to existing app users. We want to do something like versioning of our scripts and custom apis.

We searched a lot for the option to do versioning of azure mobile scripts and custom Apis. But we did not get anything relevant.

Can somebody guide me to the right direction? Is it possible to do versioning in azure mobile services node backend?

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a recommended way for doing API versioning for Mobile Services, though it's something we've thought more about recently.

One means of doing this is keeping each version of your API under a specific route, i.e. `\api\1.0.6\myAPI`. In this way, your API version ships with each client. You can use shared code behind the API to avoid any too much rework.

There's no built-in versioning for the tables endpoints--you'd have to use a service like Azure API Management, or have two mobile service backends to handle the two client versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your quick reply. If I am getting you right then you are talking about azure mobile Services custom API versioning. If I am right then YES, we can do it the way you are telling. But my query is can we do versioning of my table scripts as well? For an example, I have a Insert script for "User" table which has some breaking changes which may cause existing app to crash. In that case, to support old client and new client can I maintain azure mobile script versions ?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a better API versioning story for tables. This is something we're thinking about in our new Mobile Apps product.

Comment: OK. It means, even if we try to move to azure mobile services .Net backend then also we won't be able to achieve what we want. So can we go for asp.net web API instead for such scenarios? Will it be a good option?